# Ubuntu unable to locate openssl packet installing composer

Tags: linux, ubuntu, openssl, composer-php

```
wolf@wolf-HP-ProBook-430-G3:~$ sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends php-openssl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php-openssl
```

tried all installation commands including adding a new ssl repository at the sources.list file

Comment: Why is this tagged with Composer? What else did you try to install such a package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you think there's a separate packge? SSL support is baked into php.

```
php -r 'phpinfo();' | grep -i ssl
Registered Stream Socket Transports => tcp, udp, unix, udg, ssl, tls, tlsv1.0, tlsv1.1, tlsv1.2, tlsv1.3
openssl
OpenSSL support => enabled
OpenSSL Library Version => OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
OpenSSL Header Version => OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
Openssl default config => /usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf
openssl.cafile => no value => no value
openssl.capath => no value => no value
Native OpenSSL support => enabled
```

Here the list of packages installed on my system:

```
aptitude search ~iphp
i A libapache2-mod-php7.4                     - server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (Apach
i A php-common                                - Common files for PHP packages                       
i   php7.4                                    - server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (metap
i   php7.4-cli                                - command-line interpreter for the PHP scripting langu
i A php7.4-common                             - documentation, examples and common module for PHP   
i A php7.4-json                               - JSON module for PHP                                 
i A php7.4-opcache                            - Zend OpCache module for PHP                         
i A php7.4-readline                           - readline module for PHP
```

Comment: the problem is locating.   Unable to locate package php-openssl

Comment: It doesn't exist because it's not required. Why do you think it should exist? @Wolf_Developer This is like complaining that there's no wheel on the roof of your car. It doesn't need one there, no normal car has that.

Comment: was trying to run my laravel project on nginx local server and am new to ubuntu. thought it was neccessary